# Why specify table/column name in JPA?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I understand that there are a lot of cases when it's required to specify name of a table or column, but i also quite often see annotations like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
public class Person {

    //...
    @Column(name = "name")
    private string name;
}
```

What is the point of those annotations? Wouldn't table and column get names of the class and field automatically in this situation?

Comment: JPA has defaults defined for table/column name. The example you give above is totally pointless ... they are the defaults. Many would argue that putting such schema specific info in annotations (rather than externally, using either XML or other means) is a maintenance disaster also

Comment: `Wouldn't table and column get names of the class and field automatically in this situation?` .. can you please explain why and how they would map automatically.

Comment: @ashishpatil Because class is annotated by Entity and field is not annotated as Transient?

Comment: Yes, the `@Table` is superfluous if the table is the same name as the Entity, but it's still a good idea to at least have the `@Column` annotation (without it's name) to show which fields are columns. And you might also need to specify column parameters, like size, precision, nullable, etc.

Answer (score -1):

`@Column` Is used to specify a mapped column for a persistent property or field. If no Column annotation is specified, the default values are applied.